# ASP.NET MVC 5 Form AJAX Post Without Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a basic ASP.NET MVC 5 page with an `@HTML.BeginForm` object on it. This form is going to be very dynamic and is going to have various things added to it as the user is using it.

I want to have several buttons within this form that are going to before AJAX Post calls to the controller to gather data from a database (for populating select boxes) but I don't want them to actually submit the form. I want a single button at the bottom of the form which says "Submit" and actually submits the entire form when the user is done.

I want to have additional buttons within the `@HTML.BeginForm` object that are able to post to the server to gather data from a database without actually submitting the entire form. I have the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` library added to my page but that doesn't seem to help.

Any time a button is clicked in the form it instantly attempts to submit the entire form and refreshes the page. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own. You must have the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` library, but on top of that you must use an `<input />` element rather than a `<button />` element. I believe any `<button />` element within an `@HTML.BeginForm` element will automatically submit the form. I switched from `<button />` to `<input />` and it's working properly now.